# Instance of 'module' has no 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_create' member

Tags: python, opencv

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector= cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

def getImagesAndLabels(path):

imagePaths=[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)] 

faceSamples=[]

Ids=[]

for imagePath in imagePaths:

    pilImage=Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')

    imageNp=np.array(pilImage,'uint8')

    Id=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])

    faces=detector.detectMultiScale(imageNp)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        faceSamples.append(imageNp[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        Ids.append(Id)
return faceSamples,Ids


faces,Ids = getImagesAndLabels('dataSet')
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(Ids))
recognizer.save('trainner/trainner.yml')
```

When I run the above code it throws an error stating that

> Instance of module has no LBHPFaceRecognizer_create() member

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing opencv-contrib-python package,

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Edit 1:

Are you are using an older version of the package, if yes, there is a module name change, https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7187

You can do a quick check on what modules are available in the `cv2.face` package.

```
>>> import cv2
>>> dir(cv2.face)
['BIF_create', 'EigenFaceRecognizer_create', 'FisherFaceRecognizer_create', 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_create', 'MACE_create', 'MACE_load', 'StandardCollector_create', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'createFacemarkAAM', 'createFacemarkKazemi', 'createFacemarkLBF', 'drawFacemarks', 'getFacesHAAR', 'loadDatasetList', 'loadFacePoints', 'loadTrainingData']
```

Comment: I have already installed the opencv-contrib-python but still the problem is continuing.

Comment: Hey thanks . The LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() is present in the cv2.face but still it shows the error that instance of module has no LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() member